# Mongodump file size is very large than actual db size

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Hello Team we are using MongoDB version 4.2.13 as we check db size with show databases it is 160 GB but our Mongodump file size is 620 GB total, it is way larger than actual DB size. is there any way we resolve this. command we are using for dum is simple as below :

mongodump -u admin -p 'xxxxxxxxx' --authenticationDatabase admin --out /backup/daily_backup/$date

Answer (score 3):

The database is compressed. Check `db.stats()` for `storageSize` (Size on disk) and `dataSize` (Size of uncompressed data). Mongodump without compression saves as plain bson which should be slightly bigger than `dataSize`. If you want to compress your dump use `--gzip` parameter. Then it is not readable by simple parsing anymore, but saves storage space..